# sIFR 3 - sifr-config.js possibly not running? Not sure what's wrong

Tags: sifr

I've been messing with this for a few hours, and I just can't get the text to be replaced at all.  I really can't believe it's taking so long, especially because I did this a few months ago and got it to work in minutes.

Anyway, here is my site I'm working on:
http://www.moreheadplanetarium.org/regeneration/test/vision.php

and I want to replace the h1 tag (Morehead's Vision).  I don't know what's wrong, since I've done everything I know to do. I'm jumping back into web design and using Firebug, and when I check the scripts it only has sifr.js and sifr-debug.js in the list, so I'm assuming the config isn't loading but I have no idea what could be the hold up...

How do you get the debug to work btw?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error at the end of `sifr-config.js`.

Comment: I found that I had added another sIFR.activate(), fixed it, but it still doesn't work (it wasn't working before that iteration either...)  How do you find out where the syntax errors are?

Sorry for the v. noobish questions.

Comment: Made some progress :) it's loading, but now it's blank, but even that is a welcome sign from no change whatsoever.  Now to research this problem...

Comment: Seems to work now, although some characters appear to be missing from the Flash movie.